# Function: null(address) in contract deployment

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, eoa

I try to understand the process of contract deployment and how to determine if a rug pull is possible.

I am looking at the contract of the memecoin DOBO. During [contract deployment](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xdb2969a641f85f124b4f33978238e2bc65ce117410232763afb92ac8a9496b78) a function "null(address)" with the parameter "_RA" containing an unverified address was called:

[image: Input Data]

However I can not find such a function or parameter in the deployed [contract](https://bscscan.com/address/0xae2df9f730c54400934c06a17462c41c08a06ed8#code).

What is the meaning of such input data? Could this be a possible rug pull?

Comment: Not an answer but rug pulls are hard to identify. You'd have to look at the entire source code to see if there's any escape hatch or malicious withdrawal gateway.

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is just a bug of [bscscan.com](https://bscscan.com/), not a rug pull at all.

BSCScan tries to decode the input data using a custom-created ABI that does not correspond to the actual smart contract. (see below for reference).

This error is present on every smart contract's deployment page.

Please note that you need to read data directly from your local node to do actual research about smart contracts and potential rug pull, or any real use-case that is not a simple test.

3rd parties online explorers can be helpful for light testing, not to conduct research or verify anything that has meaningful value.

Here is the faulty ABI:

```js
var LitContractABI = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_RA","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"RA","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_pair","type":"address"}],"name":"getKValue","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"k_","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_pair","type":"address"}],"name":"getTotalValue","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_pair","type":"address"}],"name":"markdown","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_pair","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount_","type":"uint256"}],"name":"valuation","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}];
```